# tree view scrollbars do not work properly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a `tree view` with horizontal and vertical scrollbars. My code looks like this (I added some gibberish to build deep hierarchy).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("400x400")
app.title("Basic viewer")

main_window = ttk.PanedWindow(app, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL)
main_window.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10, pady=10)

tree_view_frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
tree_view_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
tree_view_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

tree_view = ttk.Treeview(tree_view_frame, selectmode = tk.BROWSE)
tree_view.heading('#0', text='Managed Archives', anchor = tk.W)
tree_view.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "nswe")

item_1 = tree_view.insert('', tk.END, text='folder 1')
item_2 = tree_view.insert(item_1, tk.END, text='folder 2')
item_3 = tree_view.insert(item_2, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_4 = tree_view.insert('', tk.END, text='folder 4')
item_5 = tree_view.insert('', tk.END, text='folder 5')
item_2 = tree_view.insert(item_1, tk.END, text='folder 2')
item_31 = tree_view.insert(item_2, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_32 = tree_view.insert(item_31, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_33 = tree_view.insert(item_32, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_34 = tree_view.insert(item_33, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_35 = tree_view.insert(item_34, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_36 = tree_view.insert(item_35, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_37 = tree_view.insert(item_36, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_38 = tree_view.insert(item_37, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_39 = tree_view.insert(item_38, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_300 = tree_view.insert(item_39, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_301 = tree_view.insert(item_300, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_302 = tree_view.insert(item_301, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_303 = tree_view.insert(item_302, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_304 = tree_view.insert(item_303, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_305 = tree_view.insert(item_304, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_306 = tree_view.insert(item_305, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_38 = tree_view.insert(item_37, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_39 = tree_view.insert(item_38, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_300 = tree_view.insert(item_39, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_38 = tree_view.insert(item_37, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_39 = tree_view.insert(item_38, tk.END, text='folder 3')
item_300 = tree_view.insert(item_39, tk.END, text='folder 3')

y_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_view_frame, orient = "vertical")
y_scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 2, rowspan = 3, sticky = "nswe")
x_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_view_frame, orient = "horizontal")
x_scroll.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nswe")
tree_view.configure(yscrollcommand = y_scroll.set, xscrollcommand = x_scroll.set)

main_window.add(tree_view_frame)

app.mainloop()
```

But it seems like while vertical scrolls works (though it does not work when trying to use cursor, but works with mouse scroll), the horizontal scroll does not work at all. It stays white and that's it.

I get something like this

[image]

Sometimes I do see the horizontal scroll working, but then it stops when I try to resize or do anything else.

What causes the problem?

I am running macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it only tooke me few hours to figure this out.

To make the scrollbars work you need to add the following at the end of your code:

```
x_scroll['command'] = tree_view.xview
y_scroll['command'] = tree_view.yview
#see explanation below
tree_view.column("#0", minwidth=1000)
```

The X Scrollbar is not working because the tree_view width will always readjust itself when you stretch or compress your window. Unfortunately unfolding the tree has no effect on the width.

To select the first column where your tree gets build use `#0`. To make the width "static" use `minwidth=1000` .  `minwidth` prevents the rezising of the width while you stretch it which would disable the x scrollbar again.

I can imagine that with this knowledge the code can be further optimized to make the minwidth dependent to some conditions. But im done for today.

Comment: Wow! But it is strange that it is not the case with the vertical scroll

Comment: Yes. I guess its because the height gets defined totally different then the width. height=tree_view_frame.configure(height=100)  and width = sum of width of columns.